# C++ am I referencing a function or data member? (reference to non-static member function must be called)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class which has a vector member which holds n sets. I'd like to access this member through public member functions, to insert items into the sets and to find items in the sets. But I get an error on compilation: *reference to non-static member function must be called*.

But I'm really confused because I don't think I'm referencing a member function, I think I'm trying to access a vector member.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {

public:
    std::vector <std::set<int>> entities(int x);
    int find(int x, int y);
    void insert(int x, int y);
    Foo(int x);
};

Foo::Foo(int x) {
    std::vector <std::set<int>> entities(x);
};

void Foo::insert(int x, int y) {
    entities[x].insert(y);   // << This causes error
};

int Foo::find(int x, int y) {
    std::set<int>::iterator iter = entities[x].find(y);  // << This causes error
    int found;
    if (iter != entities[x].end()) {  // << This causes error
        found = *iter;
    }
    return found;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what line is your error?

Comment: It's best to provide an MCVE (see help).  Makes it a lot easier for us to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Are `entries` and `entities` the same thing, or two different ones?

Comment: `entities` or `entries`? `entries` is not defined anywhere. BTW: `entities` is a function, not data member.

Comment: @ Will Briggs - Error occurs at `entities[x].insert(y);` and I will see help regarding MCVE. Thanks.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot "entities" my mistake when retyping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the class definition, `std::vector <std::set<int>> entities(int x);` declares a member function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `std::vector <std::set<int>>`.

In the constructor, `std::vector <std::set<int>> entities(x);` declares a local variable.

The member function is what "entities" refers to in your other member functions.

If you want a member *variable* called "entities", write

```
std::vector <std::set<int>> entities;
```

in the class definition and initialise it in the initialiser list:

```
Foo::Foo() : entities(x)
{ 
}
```

or, if the size isn't known at that point, resize it in the constructor body:

```
Foo::Foo() 
{ 
     entities.resize(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use parentheses to initialize data members in class definition. The following line would be treated as a function declaration.

```
std::vector <std::set<int>> entities(int x);
```

Instead, you could use constructor initialize data members.